# multiple series of leds off one 9v with switches

Tags: led, switches, wiring

I'm trying to make a fun toy for my toddler.  I have some LED's that come with a housing and on/off switch and positive/negative cable, then a bunch of led's and a few light switches I want to put in a box for him.  I've used the calculator and i'm thinking I need to split the wires from the 9v into two circuits with the switch, but I'm just not sure... since the calculators don't have a feature for a switch.  I have the voltage on the leds and the largest is 3.2 and all are 20mA.

Any help on how to do this would be great.

Answer (score 1):

It's very easy to calculate. You use the equivalent circuit of the led which is battery and ideal rectifier and you limit the current with a resistor.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f4gL3G.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

In this case you can have no more than 2 3.2 LEDs. You don't care about the switch, because it has little internal resistance which you can neglect. If you meant an e-switch, then you should add the Ron to your circuit and recalculate the R, but usually the Ron is less then 1 Ohm and you can neglect it as well. Alternatively you can use a LTSpice to simulate precisely the current through the LEDs and select a more proper resistor R. There are many applications that are doing the calculation for you like Droid Circuit Calc or some of the many web apps.